# Changing Profile Picture, and then Saving new one

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a program that has a profile page and I want to be able to switch the profile picture. I am able to change it but I am not sure how to go about saving the new picture from the files.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="profile-container">
   <image id="profileImage" src="https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/03/46/83/96/360_F_346839683_6nAPzbhpSkIpb8pmAwufkC7c5eD7wYws.jpg" />
</div>
<input id="imageUpload" type="file" name="profile_photo" placeholder="Photo" required="" capture>
      <script>
      $("#profileImage").click(function(e) {
          $("#imageUpload").click();
      });
      function fasterPreview( uploader ) {
          if ( uploader.files && uploader.files[0] ){
                $('#profileImage').attr('src', 
                   window.URL.createObjectURL(uploader.files[0]) );
          }
      }
      $("#imageUpload").change(function(){
          fasterPreview( this );
      });
      </script>
```

This is my code to change the picture, but I don't know how to save the new one. Every time I refresh the page, the picture goes back to the default.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need some sort of database to store the information. This is a pretty large ask for Stack Overflow. Check out tutorials on saving data via JS (or PHP) to a database.

Comment: Youre not actually saving it anywhere. Youre just changing it in the DOM. It will never be there when you refresh. You need to upload and save it to a server

Answer (score 0):

If using local storage is an option, I think it would solve your issue. I am not very comfortable in jquery but I think you are trying to change the src attribute if a new image is provided.
You could initially store the path to the image in local storage.

```
localstorage.setItem('imgPath', 'https://path-to-image-here');
```

Then, when a new image is uploaded, just change the path in local storage. You can show this image in your profile like this:

```
localstorage.getItem('imgPath');
```